# Find Employees with same salary using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Suppose we have a list of Employee objects { id, name, salary} . **How to find the employees having the same salary?**  using Java 8 Stream API ..

**What I tried:-**
I guess this is indirect way of asking how to list employees "based on" salary, In that case we can `groupBy` Salary.  But that will display all salary and the list of employees with that salary .

**Question:** How to list only employees with same salary from this big map?

**Solution I tried ::**

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        employees.add(new Employee(1, "John" , 1000));
        employees.add(new Employee(1, "Peter" , 2000));
        employees.add(new Employee(1, "Ben" , 3000));
        employees.add(new Employee(1, "Steve" , 2000));
        employees.add(new Employee(1, "Parker" , 1000));

Map<Integer, Set<String>> map3 =  employees.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy
                        (Employee::getSalary, Collectors.mapping
                                (Employee::getName, Collectors.toSet())));
```

OUTPUT

map3 :: {2000=[Steve, Peter], 3000=[Ben], 1000=[Parker, John]}

---

```
public class Employee {

public Employee(int id, String name, int salary) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
}

private int id;
private String name;
private int salary;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with the below **solution** that uses the **groupBy** already coded and then do a condition check on size.

```
 map3.forEach((k,v) -> {
            if(v.size()>1) {
                System.out.println("salary :: "+ k + " is same for " + v);
            }
        });
```

OR  using a **filter** , avoiding a if condition check ..

```
  map3.entrySet()
            .stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().size()>1)
            .forEach((e) -> System.out.println( "Salary :: " + 
                        e.getKey() + " is same for " + e.getValue()));
```

**OUTPUT**

salary :: 2000 is same for [Steve, Peter]

salary :: 1000 is same for [Parker, John]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use filter like this:

```
employees.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getSalary)).entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size() > 1)
            .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue()
                 .stream().map(Employee::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning on filtering over the resulting set instead of doing a if condition check .. I modified my solution accordingly. This one looks a bit complicated to me..